# Sed unknown option to `s when i try to pass 2 variables

Tags: linux, bash, sed

i have a problem with my sed command in my sh script.
I already tried without `-i`, replacing my file with a backup using `>` and cp, removing the simples quotes and trying with double after s/ and /g.

```
echo '=> Enabling Cryptodisk in GRUB'
sed -i 's/#GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y/GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y/g' /etc/default/grub #Enabling Cryptodisk in GRUB

echo '=> Adding Preload_modules in GRUB'
sed -i 's/GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="part_gpt part_msdos"/GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="part_gpt part_msdos luks cryptodisk"/g' /etc/default/grub #Adding Preload_modules in GRUB

echo '=> Adding Linux CMDLINE in GRUB'
GUIDMAPPER=$(blkid | grep ^/dev/mapper | awk -F "\"" '{print $2}') #Get mapper GUID
GUIDSDA3=$(blkid | grep ^/dev/sda3 | awk -F "\"" '{print $2}') #Get sda3 GUID
sed -i 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptdevice=${GUIDMAPPER}=${GUIDSDA3}:cryptroot root=/dev/mapper/cryptroot crypto=whirlpool:aes-xts-plain64:512:0:"/g' /etc/default/grub #Adding Linux CMDLINE in GRUB
```

The error is triggered for the last sed call, everything else work fine.

```
sed -i 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptdevice=${GUIDMAPPER}=${GUIDSDA3}:cryptroot root=/dev/mapper/cryptroot crypto=whirlpool:aes-xts-plain64:512:0:"/g' /etc/default/grub
```

Tested so far... :

```
sed -i 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptdevice='"$GUIDMAPPER"'='"$GUIDSDA3"':cryptroot root=/dev/mapper/cryptroot crypto=whirlpool:aes-xts-plain64:512:0:"/g' /etc/default/grub #Adding Linux CMDLINE in GRUB
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAJuY.png)

Thanks (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Your replacement contains `/`, try other delimiters, say `,`

Answer (score 0):

Edit :
It works by escaping '\' in replacement.

```
sed -i 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptdevice='"$GUIDMAPPER"'='"$GUIDSDA3"':cryptroot root=\/dev\/mapper\/cryptroot crypto=whirlpool:aes-xts-plain64:512:0:"/g' /etc/default/grub #Adding Linux CMDLINE in GRUB
```

Thanks to Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: With `sed -i 's,GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="",replacement,g'` you don't have to escape the slashes.